# Como ter mais de uma coluna sendo mostrada em um ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

A pergunta é a mesma do título, tenho um `ComboBox` chamado `txtProfissional` e configurei o mesmo assim:

```
txtProfissional.DataSource = modelOff.profissionals.Where(p => p.idUnidade == oUsuario.unidade);
txtProfissional.DisplayMember = "nome";
txtProfissional.ValueMember = "id";
```

Minha intenção é que na propriedade `DisplayMember` sejam listadas as colunas `nome` e `funcao`.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criar uma propriedade que faça a junção de nome e função.

Supondo que `Profissional` seja o nome da classe.

```
public class Profissional
{
    // outras propriedades
    public string NomeFuncao => $"{nome} - {funcao}";
}
```

```
txtProfissional.DisplayMember = "NomeFuncao";
txtProfissional.ValueMember = "id";
```

Se você não quiser criar a propriedade, por qualquer motivo que seja, pode criar um evento `Format` para o controle

```
private void ComboBoxFormat(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{        
    var item = (Profissional)e.ListItem;
    e.Value = "{item.Nome} - {item.Funcao}";
}
```

Comment: Eu acesso os dados de um banco de dados, e lá não existe essa coluna.

Comment: Por isso que eu disse pra criar a propriedade, @ItaloRodrigo